# How to skip BookingPress lazy load on smartphones

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins, lazy-loading, smartphone

Essentially, the lazy load of [BookingPress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/bookingpress-appointment-booking/) animation to load the form doesn’t resolve until you scroll at the screen or something on an iPhone. I have tried numerous things that just stuck temporarily with WP rocket, but can’t seem to find a permanent solution. This is my first time posting here, so I’m sorry if I’m wrong, but I guess that’s how we start.

[image]

Website link: https://doctorsondemand.co.za/book-appointment/

I tried to exclude the JavaScript from being delayed WP rocket.

I tried to disable lazy load, which the plug just overrides the CSS or the plug-in. Unfortunately, school learning this side of things. I am a bit lost.

Comment: As this seems a bug like from BookingPress plugin on smatphones (iPhone) with the Lazy load feature, maybe you should contact the plugin authors [on their support threads](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/bookingpress-appointment-booking/)

Comment: Ok yes i think that is the best way forward but they don't respond. I will look into that option a bit more